# I want to assign a specific VM permission to Ovirt users based on the VM tag

Tags: virtual-machine, ovirt

I have a group of VMs with certain tag. I would like for users (that all belong to a group) to have the UserVmManager permission for those VMs.

From what I've found, Red Hat documentation isn't particularly clear on how to do this.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so where to read about it?